# is it possible to compare strings with a special form

Tags: python, python-3.x

As of right now, this produces false. I just want to know is it possible to set a variable to set up for like special formatted types of strings

```
sting_prime = str, str

x = "jon, doe" 

print (x == sting_prime)
```

so in this example, I want the string format to be a string with a comma followed by a space and another string. Since x is in that same format i would want it to produce True.

Comment: so you want to test if a string contains `', '`?  `print(',  ' in x)`

Comment: You might want to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more? @KlausD.

Comment: @e.s. i wanna test that x is in the same format as string_prime. with your answer "jon ,doe" would be correct but for what i want to do it would be wrong

Comment: I thought the linked docs would be detailed enough. If not there are many other sources on the internet.

Comment: x can never equal `sting_prime` since `str` cannot contain both "jon" and "doe".

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expressions for this. The regular expression in the code below is pretty basic, but you can change it according to your need.

```
import re


STRING_EXP = '[a-zA-Z]+' # basic expression to match ascii strings. write more complicated ones for your needs
INT_EXP = '[0-9]+'    # basic expression to match integer

schema = "{}, {}".format(STRING_EXP, STRING_EXP)
text = "jon, jdoe"
print(True if re.search(schema, text) else False) # prints True

text = "1, 2"
print(True if re.search(schema, text) else False) # prints False

# change schema
schema = "{}, {}".format(INT_EXP, INT_EXP)
print(True if re.search(schema, text) else False) # prints True
```